# Respetar saltos de linea de contenido de un textarea al ser enviado por mail

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo un imput textarea en el cual el usuario introduce un mensaje para que este posteriormente sea enviado a través de un mail siendo el contenido del textarea el cuerpo del email

He conseguido realizar todo el proceso, pero cuando se envía el email no se respetan los saltos de linea que el usuario a introducido.

He probado diferentes soluciones que he encontrado sin éxito. Os indico los códigos que he utilizado y su resultado.

$msg:

```
Buenos días,  
Este es el contenido del textarea.
```

Código:

```
{{ nl2br($msg) }}
```

Resultado:

```
Buenos días, <br /> Este es el contenido del textarea
```

También he probado el código:

```
{{ $msg = str_replace("\n", "</br>", $msg) }}
```

Pero el resultado es el mismo, detecta los saltos de linea pero parece que no reconoce el código HTML.

Cuando el usuario envía el mensaje lo envío por post a un controlador donde tengo el código para crear el email. La estructura del cuerpo del email es a través de una vista blade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes que usar `{!! !!}` de Blade para que te muestre los `Tags de HTML` ya que `{{ }}` usa la función [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.htmlspecialchars.php) ([Visualización de datos no escapados](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#displaying-data)):

```
{!! $msg !!}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciona perfectamente